# Python functions with multiple parameter brackets

Tags: python, function

I've been having trouble understanding what `h(a)(b)` means. I'd never seen one of those before yesterday, and I couldn't declare a function this way:

```
def f (a)(b):
    return a(b)
```

When I tried to do `def f (a, b):`, it didn't work either. What do these functions *do*? How can I declare them? And, finally, **what's the difference** between `f(a, b)`and `f(a)(b)`?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Functions with multiple parameter brackets don't exist, as you saw when you tried to define one. There are, however, functions which return (other) functions:

```
def func(a):
    def func2(b):
        return a + b
    return func2
```

Now when you call `func()` it returns the inner `func2` function:

```
>>> func2 = func(1)  # You don't have to call it func2 here
>>> func2(2)
3
```

But if you don't need the inner function later on, then there's no need to save it into a variable and you can just call them one after the other:

```
>>> func(1)(2)   # func(1) returns func2 which is then called with (2)
3
```

This is a very common idiom when defining decorators that take arguments.

---

Notice that calling `func()` always creates a *new* inner function, even though they're all named `func2` inside of the definition of our `func`:

```
>>> f1 = func(1)
>>> f2 = func(1)
>>> f1(1), f2(1)
(2, 2)
>>> f1 is f2
False
```

---

> And, finally, **what's the difference** between `f(a, b)`and `f(a)(b)`?

It should be clear now that you know what `f(a)(b)` does, but to summarize:

- `f(a, b)` calls `f` with two parameters `a` and `b`
- `f(a)(b)` calls `f` with one parameter `a`, which then returns another function, which is then called with one parameter `b`

Comment: If we had two function in `func` then we should use second parameter as indices for accessing them ?

Comment: @Arman I'm not sure if I understand your question fully, can you clarify a little?

Comment: in your example you just define a `func2` function can you explain with another function like `func3` and how access it , both function are in `func` definition.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're thinking of [something like this](http://pastebin.com/6t0uBWwp)? If so, then it would be better to just use a list of functions or a function map (dict of functions) @Arman

Comment: @Arman Yes you could, but usually, if that's all you need, you can just make a list of functions `def f(): return 'foo'; def g(); return 'bar'; list_of_functions = [f, g]`, and then just use that like so: `list_of_functions[1]()`. But yes, you could use a function to do the same thing: `def function_selector(index): if index == 0: return f; if index == 1; return g` And so on. But usually, the point of using the function-returning-functions approach is because you need to do more complicated logic than just mapping indices/keys to functions.

Answer (score 19):

`f(a)(b)` just means that the expression `f(a)` returns a value that is itself callable. It's a short form of

```
g = f(a)
g(b)
```

You might be more comfortable adding a pair of redundant parentheses to emphasize that this is not a single syntactic construct.

```
(f(a))(b)  # f(a) is evaluated first, then the result is applied to b
```

---

It is exactly analogous to the same doubling of square brackets for indexing nested dictionaries.

```
d1[x][y]
```

is equivalent to

```
d2 = d1[x]
d2[y]
```

Answer (score 8):

Lets say we have an expression like

```
f(a)(b)
```

then, `f(a)` returns a function itself which gets invoked with argument `b`. Consider the following example

```
def f(a):
   def g(b):
      return a * b
   return g
```

Then `f(5)(4)` evaluates to `5 * 4`, since `f(5)` returns a function which is basically

```
def g(b):
   return 5 * b
```

One could now do stuff like this

```
mult_by_5 = f(5)
[mult_by_5(x) for x in range(10)]
```

Let's be fancy, what about more nested functions?:

```
def f(a):
  def g(b):
    def h(c):
      return a * b *c
    return h
  return g
f(2)(3)(4) # 24
```