# What does this syntax mean in Keras Dropout(0.5)(X)?

Tags: python, keras

I know that `'X'` on right-hand side is the input before you applied dropout. Now when you say `Dropout(0.5)(X)`, it means that you are randomly making the activation of 50% of the neurons in the input to zero.

This line `Dropout(0.5)` means which are making a new object of class Dropout and passing 0.5 in its constructor. But appending `X` at the end of it? What does this mean in Python Syntax?

Comment: did this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874825/python-functions-with-multiple-parameter-brackets

Comment: Thanks, it did help.@Rahul!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways that this code can work, 2 come into my mind right now:

Using the built in `__call__` function of classes

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, name):
...             self.name = name
...     def __call__(self, word):
...             print(self.name, 'says', word)
...
>>> MyClass('Tom')('hello')
Tom says hello
```

A function returning a function

```
>>> def add(a):
...     def f2(b):
...             print(a+b)
...     return f2
...
>>> add(1)(2)
3
```

I hope this helps

Comment: After having a look in the source ([Github Keras Dropout](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/layers/core.py#L119)) it turns out that actually the `__call__`-approach has been used in this case. Thanks for sharing both possible approaches!