# What does the parenthesis after the function mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I was asked to write a function in Python 3 for:
Write a function called `general_poly`, that would, for example, evaluate `general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])(10)` to `1234` because `1*10^3 + 2*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 4*10^0`.

Now I don't understand what the second parenthesis, `(10)`, means.

How would my function `general_poly` know, to take that value inside itself and use it?

Comment: it means that the function wil return function and the returned function will becalled  with 10 as argument. So your general_poly shod return function which will use 10 as a base. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874825/python-functions-with-multiple-parameter-brackets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means that your function should return a function:

```
def multiplier(times):
    def inner(num):
         return num * times
    return inner

result = multiplier(2)(3)
print(result)
# 6

times_four = multiplier(4)
print(times_four(3))
# 12
```

This may or may not be an overkill, but if you need to save state you can even use a class and implement `__call__`:

```
class multiplier:
    def __init__(self, times):
        self.times = times
    def __call__(self, num):
        return num * self.times

print(multiplier(2)(3))
# 6
```

Comment: Ah, now I understand, it returns a function without the parenthesis and then uses the second parenthesis as input. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

A function is a [first-class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects) in Python. One of the corollaries of this is that a function may return another function.

Your particular example can be written as follows:

```
def general_poly(A):
    k = len(A)
    def power(n):
        return sum(j*n**(k-i) for i, j in enumerate(A, 1))
    return power

res = general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])(10)  # 1234
```

The outer function `general_poly` *returns* the inner function `power`. The former takes a list, or an array, while the latter takes a scalar.

---

An alternative way of structuring your logic is to use `functools.partial`. This creates a new function which one or more parameters fixed and obviates the need for an inner function.

```
from functools import partial

def general_poly(A, n):
    k = len(A)
    return sum(j*10**(k-i) for i, j in enumerate(A, 1))

genral_poly_10 = partial(general_poly, n=10)
res = genral_poly_10([1, 2, 3, 4])  # 1234
```

Of course, this is only useful if you wish to create a function for a specific power; trivially, `n` can be used directly as an additional parameter without `functools.partial`.

---

**Note**: [Beware of mutable default arguments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments). So if your function has a mutable default argument, e.g. setting `A=[]` in the above examples, the same list may be reused in an unforeseen way.

Comment: Be very, very careful with this approach. The mutable default argument gotcha is still relevant when using `partial`.

Comment: @DeepSpace, Agreed, I'll add a disclaimer :)

Answer (score 1):

The second set of paranthesis don't actually interact with the function, they apply to whatever the function returns. It's the same principle as `returnsAList()[0]`, which would give you the first element of the list returned by `returnsAList()`.